# UIAlertView changes UITabbar item selected color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitabbaritem

I've got a strange problem in my application: i've a `UIViewController` that present an `UIAlertView` when an user taps on a button. The alert let the user choose between the Photo Library and the iPhone camera.

When the alert shows up, i notice this issue:

First, the `UIViewController` selected tab bar items has this layout

[image: selected tab bar item]

Then, when the alert shows up, it changes like this

[image: selected tab bar item when alert is been shown]

And if the user decides to access his photo library and then it returns back, the tab bar item remains like this

[image: selected tab bar after accessing the photo library]

How is that possible? Maybe the UIAlertView is changing some tint color?

Thanks

Comment: what tintColor do you set for tabs? also check selectedImageTintColor

Comment: @purrrminator For the tab bar tint color and selectedImageTintColor i used `[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:96.0/255.0 green:194.0/255.0 blue:224.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well where certain views will sometimes stay dimmed when they should return to their normal color after dismissing a `UIAlertView`. I believe it is a bug in iOS 7.0 (or possibly 7.1). I put this workaround in my `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        self.window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This prevents all views from dimming in the first place, which in turn keeps all your views in your app from staying dimmed.

Comment: If you're using a custom `UIView` subclass, make sure you implement `tintColorDidChange`, per [Andrea’s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23536818/1148702) suggestion below

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a custom UIView subclass? here is what Apple states in the transition guide.

> When an alert or action sheet appears, iOS 7 automatically dims the
>   tint color of the views behind it. To respond to this color change, a
>   custom view subclass that uses tintColor in its rendering should
>   override tintColorDidChange to refresh the rendering when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you, but it happens in UISlider. I solved my problem: just set color for my UISlider.

```
 progressSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

**I think you just set color for this tab bar item**

**If you don't set color for tab bar item it will be reset to lightGrayColor after alert is shown**

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me when I tried to show a UIAlertView in viewDidLoad. I solved this by showing it in viewDidAppear. You can find a sample [here https://github.com/Tulakshana/TabBar](https://github.com/Tulakshana/TabBar)